# Installing cassandra without openjdk dependency

Tags: java, centos, dependencies, yum, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to install cassandra from datastax.I have installed oracle jdk7. The first brick wall I hit was:

```
  yum install jna.
```

It strikes openjdk dependency.

```
  java-1.7.0-openjdk                              
  java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless
```

Again, when I install cassandra:

```
yum install dsc20.
```

I got dependency issue:

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk                              
  java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless  
  javapackages-tools
```

How do I install datastax cassandra without installing openjdk?

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a lot of time googling and trying to figure out quite similar issue and at the end of a day it seems there are 2 options that make sense:

1. *(recommended)* Just install the OpenJDK as a dependency and then set proper `JAVA_HOME` pointing to Oracle's Java.
2. Download and rebuild/modify existing RPM with changed dependencies in its manifest. Then deploy it somewhere (own yum repo?) and install as regular yum package.

Since option 1 just install one redundant package (that you effectively shadow by using `JAVA_HOME`), it's just OK for me.